# How to disable Ctrl+F6, Ctrl+Tab and Ctrl+F4 in an MDI program

Tags: winapi, mfc, keyboard-shortcuts

I need to disable <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> (close document), <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> (next pane) and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> (next document) shortcuts in an MFC MDI program. These shortcuts are handled automatically by MFC (or even Win32 ?).

Is there an easy way do to this ? I was thinking to intercept the corresponding keystrokes in `PreTranslateMessage`, but this seems more of a hack to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`TranslateMDISysAccel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644926%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) Win32 function is responsible for turning those keypresses into `WM_SYSCOMMAND` messages. It's called as part of a "standard" MDI message loop (pseudo-code):

```
while (GetMessage())
{
    if (!TranslateMDISysAccel() && !TranslateAccelerator())
    {
        TranslateMessage();
        DispatchMessage();
    }
}
```

Therefore, in a pure Win32 program the solution would be to simply not call `TranslateMDISysAccel` as part of your message loop if you don't want those keys to be handled.

I'm assuming that in an MFC-based program this detail is hidden from you. It would seem then that overriding the `PreTranslateMessage` function would be the appropriate solution. There is quite a good discussion of this technique [here](https://binglongx.wordpress.com/2011/03/20/pretranslatemessage-overrides-in-mfc-and-grab-key-presses/).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make it simple, in your IDR_MAINFRAME accelerator table, add entries for those key combinations, and make them execute a command that is either undefined or routes to a command that does nothing.

When the CMDIFrameWnd::PreTranslateMessage() function is called, it will intercept those accelerators and issue the command which your app will ignore.  The TranslateMDISysAccel() function will never be called for those hotkey combinations because there are the entries in your resource ACCEL table.